# How do I rerender UI after updating state in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a list of saved item that I want to be able to "unsave" any item I want.
I successfully deleted the item from the saved list but I have to reload the page for it to show the updated list (after deleting the item).
How do I update it instantaneously in the UI?

In saved.js (reducer):

```
const initialState = {
  savedItems: [],
  }
...
case UNSAVE_ITEM: {
      if (!error) {
        const {user_un_favorite} = payload;
        if (user_un_favorite && user_un_favorite.ok) {
          const savedItems = state.savedItems || [];
          return {
            ...state,
            savedItems: savedItems.filter(i => i.id != payload.id)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In Saved.js screen

```
...
 renderSavedCards = () => {
    const { savedItems } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="list-right">
        {savedItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="savedCard">
                <SearchCard
          
                 data={item.data}
                 
                />
                <span
                  className="deleteSaved"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    this.props.unSaveItem(item.id);
                  }}
                >
                  <IcTrash className='trash-icon'/>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderLoadMore()}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Try to put `savedItems: [...savedItems.filter(i => i.id != payload.id)]` in your reducer ?

Comment: No It doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, hmmm, then are you sure that your `UNSAVE_ITEM` action is called correctly ?
Try to put a `console.log` after `const savedItems = state.savedItems || [];` and see if this is logged.
If it is, then, you maybe should try to totally rebuild your `savedItem` array.
Get the deleted element's index with a `savedItems.findIndex(elem => elem.id === payload.id)` and then `savedItems: [...savedItems.slice(0, index), savedItems.slice(index + 1)]`
(I hope it's clear enough)

Comment: I think it was called correctly . That's why I was able to delete the item. But I had to reload the page to see the updated list

Comment: So the error is in your `case UNSAVE_ITEM: {}` for sure.
With React's lifecycle, this shouldn't require a reload